# creation of Simple errored: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, remix, ether

```
contract Simple is Ownable {
    
    using SafeMath for uint;
    
    address                      public  fuel;
    uint                         public  initTime;

    
    constructor( address _fuel, uint timer) public {
        // factory = IJustSwapFactory(msg.sender);
        fuel = _fuel;
        initTime = now.add(timer) ;
    }
}
```

I am receiving this error when working my code:

> creation of Trading errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

Why does the constructor need to be payable?

Comment: The constructor needs to be payable only if you pass a value (amount of ether) when you create the contract. We don't know whether or not this is what you're doing, because you haven't posted your actual deployment code!

Comment: If you're not passing ether, then the contract creation (deployment) fails because of something in its actual code. Assuming that the first line in it is indeed commented out as shown in your question, the only thing that can cause that passing an extremely large value of `timer`, which would cause the value of `now + timer` to overflow. Again, we have no idea what value of `timer` you are passing, because you haven't posted the relevant details. Please do so.

Comment: It brings the same error, when I comment out the whole constructor as well. I've worked this code out in the past, but it worked out fine.

Comment: @HakobArshakyan It does work as expected here using remix with JS VM environment. Which EVM environment do you use? What's solidity version? Are you sure deploying Simple, or perhaps some other contract instead?

Comment: @Ismael, The problem was that I was mentioning the some amount of ether for the constructor transaction, for which it was unnecessary. Once I made the value of the transaction 0, it just worked fine. Thanks for your feedback.